# Why is the screen being showed not changing on update of the screen's index?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a mainPage.dart file with a bottomNavigationBar that onTap of a button changes a global variable called currentIndex. The body of the mainPage file is set to show the screen from a list of screens at the currentIndex. The problem is that the screen doesn't change when the bottomNavigationBar updates the currentIndex. I'm sorry if this is unclear, but it makes more sense in the code sample:

mainPage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:taskapp/screens/home/addTask.dart';
import 'package:taskapp/screens/home/home.dart';
import 'package:taskapp/taskGlobals.dart';                         // <= currentIndex is in here
import 'home/widgets/appBars.dart' as buildNavigationBars;

class mainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<mainPage> createState() => _mainPageState();
}

class _mainPageState extends State<mainPage> {
  final screens = [
    HomePage(),
    addTask(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60),
          child: buildNavigationBars.topNavBar()),
      body: screens[currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: buildNavigationBars.BottomNavBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

The appBars.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:taskapp/screens/home/addTask.dart';
import 'package:taskapp/screens/home/home.dart';
import 'package:taskapp/taskGlobals.dart';

class BottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildBottomNavigationBar();
  }
}

class topNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildAppBar();
  }
}

Widget _buildBottomNavigationBar(Function(int) onTap) {
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
          topRight: Radius.circular(30),
        ),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
              spreadRadius: 5,
              blurRadius: 10)
        ]),
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
        topRight: Radius.circular(30),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: GlobalVariable().currentIndex(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
        onTap: onTap,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Home',
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_rounded, size: 30),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Tasks',
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_task_rounded, size: 30),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

AppBar _buildAppBar() {
  return AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    elevation: 0,
    title: Row(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 45,
          width: 45,
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/avatar.jpeg'),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        const Text(
          'Hi Amit',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 26, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    actions: const [
      Icon(
        Icons.more_vert,
        color: Colors.black,
        size: 40,
      )
    ],
  );
}

}
```

Task Globals:

```
library myprj.taskGlobals;

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

int currentIndex = 0;                                             // currentIndex

DocumentSnapshot snapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('name I would not like to share for privacy')
    .doc('another name')
    .get() as DocumentSnapshot;
```

Comment: could you include taskGlobals class too?

Comment: Just added it @eamirho3ein

Answer (score 0):

Whenever updating a variable inside a StatefulWidget you need to call `setState((){});` to make the Widget rebuild with the new values.

```dart
onTap: (index) => setState(() { currentIndex = index;}),
```

Comment: I tried this before and got an error "The function 'setState' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines 'setState', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'setState'," so I thought setState must be the wrong way to do it in this case and came here to ask.

Comment: Thats because your `Widget _buildBottomNavigationBar(Function(int) onTap)` function is not in a Stateful Widget. You need to use a Stateful widget when you want to update the widget from inside itself.

Answer (score 0):

First define your `currentIndex` here:

```
class _mainPageState extends State<mainPage> {
  int currentIndex = 0; 
  final screens = [
    HomePage(),
    addTask(),
  ];

...
}
```

then change `BottomNavBar` class and `_buildBottomNavigationBar` to this:

```
class BottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(int) onTap;
  BottomNavBar({@requird this.onTap});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildBottomNavigationBar(onTap);
  }
}


Widget _buildBottomNavigationBar(Function(int) onTap) {
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
  ...
    )
  );
}
```

and use that `onTap` you pass inside `_buildBottomNavigationBar` like this:

```
onTap: onTap,
```

then in your `mainPage` class do this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: buildNavigationBars.BottomNavBar(
  (index){
    setState(() {
         currentIndex = index;  
    });
  }
),
```

Comment: Just tried it but it didn't change screens

Comment: @FrostByte did you try my last update?

Comment: What should I then do at the top of buildNavBars: class BottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildBottomNavigationBar(); // error: 1 positional argument expected, none found
  }
}

Comment: You didn't add buildNavBars class to your code. please update your question. @FrostByte

Comment: Just added the whole file

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out @FrostByte

Comment: For some reason the page is still not changing after these updates. Is there anymore code I should share that may help? I really don't see why your solution didn't work, it makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248530/discussion-between-eamirho3ein-and-frostbyte).